# How to sava data from Ext.Store to array?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a array.

```
var new_data = [['333333.333','44444.222'], ['4444.222','78777.1111']];
```

I have a store.

```
var datastore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                                 fields: [
                                  {name: 'X', type: 'float'},
                                  {name: 'Y', type: 'float'}
                                 ]
                               });
datastore.loadData(new_data);
```

i have a editorgrid.

```
                            var cm_koord = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
                                columns: [
                                    {header: "X", 
                                    dataIndex:"X",
                                    editor: new Ext.form.TextField({allowBlank: false})
                                    },{
                                    header:"Y",
                                    dataIndex:"Y",
                                    editor: new Ext.form.TextField({allowBlank: false})
                                    }]
                            })
                            var koord_tab = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
                                title:"Симантика",
                                store: datastore,
                                region: 'center',
                                cm: cm_koord,
                                //height: 100,
                                autoScroll: true,
                                //bbar:[saveButton,cancelButton,editButton]
                            })
```

Question: How to save changes after editing? I mean how to save change in `new_data` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the getRange method on your arrayStore like this:

```
new_data = [];
Ext.each(datastore.getRange(), function (rec) {
    var rec_data = [];
    rec.commit();
    for (var i in rec.data) {
        rec_data.push(rec.data[i]);
    }
    new_data.push(rec_data);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its nice. But how about something what sae changes in source array? Why `datastore.commitChanges( );` dont do this?

Comment: I can't test right now but can't you just call each record's commit method before looping through its data?